# Unable to execute Instance Variables

Tags: ruby

I am trying to learn Instance Variables in Ruby Language.
So please excuse if this is a dumb question.

```
class Instance
  def method1
    @hello = "hello"
    p hello
  end
  Instance.new.method1()
end
```

**When I tried to run the above Program, it's giving me the folowing error**

> > C:\Documents and Settings\Sai\Desktop\RubySamples>ruby Instance.rb
> >     Instance.rb:4:in `method1': undefined local variable or method`hello' for #`<Instance:0xf09fa8 @hello="hello">` (NameError)
> >
> > > from Instance.rb:6:in `<class:Instance>'
> > >
> > >       from Instance.rb:1:in`'

The same above program is working fine for local variables that is if i remove the @ symbol from hello.

Comment: `hello` isn't defined in `method1`.  instead `p @hello`.

Comment: Also, you are trying to instantiate a class `Instance` inside of it's scope, that makes no sence.

Comment: Please compare the name of the variable in line 3 with the name of the variable in line 4. Notice anything?

Comment: Before ask questions like this, you better read at least [Ruby Programming Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming)

Answer (score 4):

no question is stupid. you're assigning a value to a instance variable, but you're calling a local variable (or method) below.

`@hello` is an instance variable which is available in a scope of an instance and it differs from `hello` which is a local variable.

Here is a nice read about [instance](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html) and [local](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/localvars.html) variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions that work:

First, using Accessors for instance variables (second line):

```
class Instance
  attr_accessor :hello
  def method1
    @hello = "hello"
    p hello
  end
  Instance.new.method1()
end
```

Second, using the instance variable directly:

```
class Instance
  def method1
    @hello = "hello"
    p @hello
  end
  Instance.new.method1()
end
```

One additional idea: I would call the method outside of the class definition:

```
class Instance
  def method1
    @hello = "hello"
    p @hello
  end
end
Instance.new.method1()
```